# Express 4 Router app.use not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have a POST request to an Express server and it's getting a 404

```
POST /batch/Job 404
```

in my Express middleware (app.js) I have this:

```
app.use('/batch/:collection',require('./routes/batch'));
```

and the `routes/batch.js` file looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.param('collection', function (req, res, next, collectionName) {

    next();
});

router.post(function(req,res,next){

    res.send({});
});



router.all(function (req, res, next) {

    res.send({});
});


module.exports = router;
```

on the front-end it looks like this:

```
               var json = {models:saveArray};

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/batch/Job',
                    data:json,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST'

                }).done(function (msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    cb(msg, textStatus, jqXHR);

                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('collection batch persist failed.')

                }).always(function (a, textStatus, b) {

                });
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the 404 error happens. The front-end code shouldn't really matter, because the server log clearly shows that a request is going to that url (/batch/Job).

When I debug, none of the breakpoints in routes/batch.js get reached, but I *can* confirm that the app.use middleware is hit when there is a POST request to batch/Job. So somewhere between the app.use call and the module that exports the router instance, there's a 'disconnect'.

Here is some proof:

[image]

as you can see, there is a breakpoint and request is hitting that line, but it's not being forwarded to the router instance. No idea why. I can confirm that the path to the module is correct, if it wasn't the error I get would be more clear.

Comment: Did you try `router.post('/', function(req,res,next){` instead?

Comment: `app.use('/batch/',require('./routes/batch'));`

and

`router.post('/:collection', function(req, res, next){..});`

Comment: yeah but it's strange that the next() call inside router.param is not reached at all

Comment: How is it different to the way you're handling the /jobs route?